# Is it possible to "mod" the action of a symmetric group on a symmetric operad?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, operads

I am relatively new to category theory, so only have a rough understanding of the technicalities behind operads. My understanding is that symmetric operads are defined so that they are "nicely" acted on by the symmetric group.

My question is: Is it possible to alter this action i.e. quotient the action so that a proper subgroup of the symmetric group acts on the operad?

I do not see how this would raise any issues with the definition of the symmetric operad (for example I think you still have equivariance), but am wondering if any technicalities would prevent me from doing this.

Comment: For full disclosure, I know nothing about operads. But in all the applications I know of, if a group acts on something, so does any of its proper subgroups, and you don't need to take a quotient to realize this action, it's just a restriction.

Comment: I don't understand the question. An operad consists of various bits which have various symmetric group actions on them. You can certainly take a particular operad and restrict these actions to subgroups. But it sounds like what you want is to alter the *definition*, to make a new type of operad involving actions by various subgroups of the symmetric groups. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I'm wondering if I can define a new type of operad by somehow altering the action of the symmetric group on a symmetric operad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5910) (This paper formulates extra structure on a sequence $G_0,G_1,\dots$ of groups to get a theory analogous to the theory of operads.)